# How to find spid of SQL Agent job that is running or has already run?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-job

I am having difficulties trying to find the SPID of a job that is still running over a certain timeframe or has already ran. Does anyone know where I can find that? I do know that I can look at the master.sys.sysprocesses table to find the spid's that are known to SQL Server.

This is one of my many tries:

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT sj.name, sja.run_requested_date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), sja.stop_execution_date - sja.start_execution_date, 114) AS Duration, sj.job_id, sj.enabled
FROM            msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sja INNER JOIN
                         msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS sj ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE        (sja.run_requested_date IS NOT NULL) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), sja.stop_execution_date - sja.start_execution_date, 114) > CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), '00:00:02:000', 114))
ORDER BY sja.run_requested_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Adam Machanic's [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com) to get this info.

For historical data I run it every minute and capture the output to a table.
Brent Ozar has an article on how to do this [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/logging-activity-using-sp_whoisactive-take-2/).